# (applescript) how to close untitled tabs?

Tags: tabs, safari, applescript

does anyone know a applescript that can automatically close untitled tabs. Im working on a router cracker for mac called router fire.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tell application "Safari" to close (tabs of window 1 whose name = "Untitled")
```